How to calculate multicollinearity when not using a regression analysis
I'm looking for guidance on addressing multicollinearity in a non-regression context. My study examines various environmental parameters (e.g., soil chemistry metrics) across three soil types (see table below). I've visualized each parameter across soil types with boxplots, performed a PCA to explore clustering, and analyzed correlations between these environmental factors and the dominant soil species.
Following my supervisor's advice, I assessed multicollinearity among the environmental parameters. Where multicollinearity was identified, the goal was to retain a single representative variable from each correlated group for further analysis. I started with Pearson correlation tests, using an ² threshold of >0.9 to flag multicollinearity. This approach identified strong correlations among Dissolved Organic Carbon (DOC), Dissolved Nitrogen (DN), Organic Carbon (C%), Organic Nitrogen (N%), and conductivity, so I selected DOC as a representative variable.
However, in exploring multicollinearity further, I've noted that discussions around this topic are often tied to regression analysis. For instance, the Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) is frequently recommended to detect multicollinearity but appears specific to regression applications, which do not apply to my analysis.
So, my primary question is: What methods are suitable for assessing multicollinearity in non-regression contexts, and are there recommended approaches in the literature that support this?
Thank you for any insights!



Soil
pH
Conductivity (uS/cm)
DOC (mg/g soil)
DN (mg/g soil)
N%
C%
C/N
ATP (nmol/g soil)




Manure
6.98
194.50
0.526
0.074
1.56
19.72
12.68
22.88


Manure
7.08
167.50
0.444
0.06
1.56
19.02
12.22
12.91


Manure
7.09
191.10
0.467
0.079
1.61
19.75
12.28
11.68


Manure
6.96
207.00
0.494
0.066
1.61
20.41
12.72
10.06


Manure
7.09
193.70
0.481
0.076
1.52
19.45
12.79
27.31


Manure
7.01
186.40
0.32
0.043
1.61
20.68
12.85
42.08


Manure
7.11
199.00
0.465
0.056
1.69
21.12
12.49
31.51


Manure
7.05
193.90
0.496
0.065
1.64
20.43
12.47
28.71


Manure
7.15
204.00
0.45
0.057
1.79
22.37
12.51
65.4


Manure
7.01
202.00
0.525
0.065
1.56
19.35
12.43
16.05


Manure
7.10
192.30
0.473
0.065
1.53
21.04
13.93
15.76


Manure
7.08
178.80
0.43
0.086
1.43
19.77
14.05
13.15


Sand
7.44
60.00
0.03
0.008
0.03
0.21
6.15
0.1


Manure
7.12
170.70
0.43
0.056
1.52
19.44
12.8
10.05


Peat
6.90
76.30
0.182
0.013
0.27
4.84
18.1
7.01


Sand
7.28
56.30
0.022
0.006
0.05
0.15
3.46
0.16


Sand
7.27
49.10
0.046
0.006
0.03
0.15
4.76
0.15


Sand
7.32
58.50
0.022
0.006
0.04
0.16
4.2
0.19


Sand
7.15
66.30
0.024
0.005
0.05
0.21
4.88
0.3


Sand
7.25
65.80
0.02
0.006
0.04
0.13
3.11
0.23


Sand
7.04
65.30
0.023
0.006
0.04
0.18
4.79
0.41


Sand
7.30
64.80
0.022
0.006
0.06
0.16
2.42
0.06


Sand
7.31
65.10
0.018
0.006
0.05
0.13
2.39
0.19


Sand
7.01
65.90
0.021
0.006
0.05
0.14
2.69
0.23


Peat
6.95
83.70
0.157
0.015
0.3
5.41
17.92
3.34


Peat
7.07
71.40
0.111
0.009
0.29
4.99
17.28
3.49


Peat
6.92
75.80
0.178
0.027
0.25
4.38
17.8
5.64


Peat
7.07
72.50
0.168
0.018
0.28
4.92
17.36
4.87


Peat
6.95
74.10
0.195
0.025
0.31
5.58
17.76
13.16


Peat
6.88
85.70
0.185
0.019
0.27
4.65
17.01
3.62


Peat
6.96
67.50
0.126
0.017
0.16
2.25
13.68
3.94


Peat
6.89
111.40
0.242
0.045
0.45
8.16
18.13
5.8


Peat
6.94
76.00
0.145
0.015
0.27
4.46
16.73
3.2


Peat
6.92
80.80
0.183
0.021
0.39
7.11
18.25
4.53


Peat
6.86
72.20
0.182
0.014
0.33
5.78
17.75
2.94


Peat
6.89
76.10
0.172
0.02
0.27
4.69
17.32
4.08




Interesting question, but off topic here; try [stats.SE] instead. That said, bear in mind "multicollinearity" just means the data points occupy a lower-dimensional subset -- the data might be nominally n-dimensional, but actually all falling on an m-dimensional subset, with m < n. That's typically interpreted to mean you don't have n independent variables, but only m. The singular value decomposition (SVD) is a standard way to look at your data to investigate if that's the case. The case m < n has implications for regression, to be sure, but it is not limited to regression.
